# Setting up load balancer frontend with on GCP with Pulumi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, bucket, pulumi

Right now I'm learning how to setup a website served by a GCP bucket using Pulumi however, I've stuck at the last step exposing an IP address and attaching it to the LB. Everything looks good except `This load balancer has no frontend configured`

I think the `ForwardingRule` is what I need but it doesn't except the `BucketBackend` (see code and output below).

Any suggestions on how to move forward?

```
####### WEBSITE ##########
web_bucket = gcp.storage.Bucket('web',
    project="myproj",
    cors=[gcp.storage.BucketCorArgs(
        max_age_seconds=3600,
        methods=[
            "GET",
        ],
        origins=["https://myproj.com", "https://sandbox.myproj.com"],
        response_headers=["*"],
    )],
    force_destroy=True,
    location="US",
    uniform_bucket_level_access=True,
    website=gcp.storage.BucketWebsiteArgs(
        main_page_suffix="index.html",
        not_found_page="404.html",
    ),
)
pulumi.export('web bucket', web_bucket.url)

ssl_certificate = gcp.compute.SSLCertificate("SSLCertificate",
    project="myproj",
    name_prefix="certificate-",
    private_key=(lambda path: open(path).read())("ssl/private.key"),
    certificate=(lambda path: open(path).read())("ssl/certificate.crt"))

http_health_check = gcp.compute.HttpHealthCheck("httphealthcheck",
    project="myproj",
    request_path="/",
    check_interval_sec=1,
    timeout_sec=1
)

# Backend Bucket Service
web_backend = gcp.compute.BackendBucket("web-backend",
    project="myproj",
    description="Serves website",
    bucket_name=web_bucket.name,
    enable_cdn=True
)

# LB Backend hostpath and rules
url_map = gcp.compute.URLMap("urlmap",
    project="myproj",
    description="URL mapping",
    default_service=web_backend.id,
    host_rules=[gcp.compute.URLMapHostRuleArgs(
        hosts=["myproj.io"],
        path_matcher="allpaths",
    )],
    path_matchers=[gcp.compute.URLMapPathMatcherArgs(
        name="allpaths",
        default_service=web_backend.id,
        path_rules=[gcp.compute.URLMapPathMatcherPathRuleArgs(
            paths=["/*"],
            service=web_backend.id,
        )],
    )]
)

# Route to backed (bucket backend)
target_https_proxy = gcp.compute.TargetHttpsProxy("targethttpsproxy",
    project="myproj",
    url_map=url_map.id,
    ssl_certificates=[ssl_certificate.id])

# Forwarding rule for External Network Load Balancing using Backend Services
web_forward = gcp.compute.ForwardingRule("webforward",
    project="myproj",
    region="us-central1",
    port_range="80",
    backend_service=web_backend.id # this doesn't work
)
```

```
Diagnostics:
  gcp:compute:ForwardingRule (default):
    error: 1 error occurred:
        * Error creating ForwardingRule: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.backendService': 'https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/myproj/global/backendBuckets/web-backend-576fa1b'. Unexpected resource collection 'backendBuckets'., invalid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong fowarding rule class. Because of the LB setup regional forwarding was wrong.

```
# Forwarding rule for External Network Load Balancing using Backend Services
web_forward = gcp.compute.GlobalForwardingRule("webforward",
    project="myproj",
    port_range="443",
    target=nbprod_target_https_proxy.self_link
)
```

Comment: Appreciate this a lot, I wish your code here was an official tutorial, it's pretty much the Pulumi equivalent of https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website. Thanks!

Comment: For those coming along later, https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/managedsslcertificate/ also provides a useful end to end guide for the most part.